# Missing some subscriptions in Azure DevOps UI when using automatic service principal

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines, active-directory

I am trying to select a subscription I have access to in another tenant from my Azure DevOps UI where I am connected to the Azure tenant AAD as a member with external login and certain permissions/roles.

In this case I want to select a subscription that I have created a resource group and an app service in so that I can create the deployment pipeline using a pre-configured template in Azure DevOps.

Previously, my account on Azure DevOps was user1@company.com and the account in Azure portal was user1@company.onmicrosoft.com as it was a different AAD. I have since added user1@company.com to the AAD of the Azure portal where the subscription resides and given it some permissions to access these subscriptions. MFA is set up on both accounts.

The really frustrating thing about this is that I did get it working temporarily last night and could both select the subscription in AzureDevOps and login when prompted with the user1@company.com account but today it seems to have reverted back to be missing the subscriptions from the additional tenant.

It is also an issue when I try to set up a new service connection but assuming it depends on same permissions in place.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you can't just use the manual SP approach? I have also had issues in the past using the `automatic` flow as well, so I usually just add in my SP creds and get on with it rather than hope all my default subscriptions have been exposed for each tenant etc.

Comment: Yes, I have manual SP working now okay but there was a particular pipeline template I wanted to use and it required a subscription with a linux app service and a web app in place. Too be honest the manual SP approach is much simpler when you are dealing with cross tenant stuff so will use this in future. The automatic approach is extremely finicky, but I did get this working eventually.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer just for anyone in future, so it is to use manual service principals with a service connection in Azure DevOps when you are dealing with cross tenant subscriptions. Automatic SP is okay if you are logged into same AD in Azure Portal and Azure DevOps but anything other than that then manual is a lot more manageable. Thanks.